# About Oracle SQL process

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle10g

I want to follow SQL transaction in Oracle. We have a software tool with 10g oracle system. The program is slowing down somewhere and I want to find that part. I could not see the event log. What do you think i can do? Is there a 3rd party software?

Thanks.

Comment: It is difficult to tell with so little information. Please try to be specific on your question, add as much information as you can about your problem and try to do a more depth research on your behalf prior to post.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle offers tracing tools. See documentation - [Using Application Tracing Tools](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/sqltrace.htm#g33356) in the Performance Tuning Guide.

It is the **TKPROF** which is reliable and will show you exactly what is going on when you use the application, along with timings so - once you examine the result - you'll be able to do further steps and tune your code.

Sample output (just to show what I'm referring to):

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0          0
Execute      1     29.60      60.68     266984      43776     131172      28144
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0          0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
total        2     29.60      60.68     266984      43776     131172      28144

                              ^^^^^
                              This!
```

So, if you find that *something* takes a minute (60 seconds, right?) to complete, that might be suspicious.